# Config, examples and use cases of Library Of Babel

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I want to understand how org-babel's Library Of Babel works. Seems like a powerful yet underused tool.

The documentation says that I can

> add code to the library, by first saving the code in regular ‘src’ code blocks of an Org file, and then load the Org file with org-babel-lob-ingest, which is bound to C-c C-v i.

What is that `org-babel-lob-ingest` truly doing? It is just appending all source blocks within an Org File to another file?

And what are the use cases of this? Can I see what I have in my Library interactively? Can I use noweb syntax with source blocks within the Library? What do I need to do to start using it?

Any examples and links to tutorials are very welcome.

Comment: It is appending the list of named source blocks it finds in the file to the variable `org-babel-library-of-babel`. When looking for source blocks, org-babel looks in the current file as well as the list stored in the above variable. The answer by @mutbuerger describes the details very well I think.

Answer (score 10):

There is a nice introduction to the library of babel in `library-of-babel.org` which is located in Org’s source directory. To use those examples of named source-code blocks in other files, populate the `org-babel-library-of-babel` variable with

```
#+begin_src elisp :results scalar
(org-babel-lob-ingest "/path/to/org-mode/doc/library-of-babel.org")
#+end_src

#+results:
: 21
```

One of the 21 blocks is named “transpose” and probably does what it’s supposed to do:

```
#+name: tbl
| a | 1 |
| d | 2 |
| a | 3 |
| d | 4 |
| d | 5 |
| c | 6 |

#+begin_src elisp :results table :post transpose(table=*this*) :var var=tbl
var
#+end_src

#+results:
| a | d | a | d | d | c |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
```

You may as well add your own code blocks, especially something you may find yourself using a lot in the future. As an example, the following allows me to aggregate values in the named table by the first column:

```
#+name: aggregatebycol1
#+begin_src elisp :results table :var table='() fun='()
(let (res)
  (mapc
   (lambda (x)
     (push `(,(car x) ,(apply fun (mapcar 'cadr (cdr x)))) res))
   (seq-group-by 'car table))
  (nreverse res))
#+end_src
```

Save the block in any file and add it to `org-babel-library-of-babel`:

```
#+begin_src elisp :results scalar
(org-babel-lob-ingest (buffer-file-name))
#+end_src

#+results:
: 1

#+header: :post aggregatebycol1(table=*this*, fun='+)
#+begin_src elisp :results table :var var=tbl
var
#+end_src

#+results:
| a |  4 |
| d | 11 |
| c |  6 |
```

Answer (score 6):

TL;DR: Using a persistent library of babel stored in one file can be a simple 3-step setup:

- Create an `org`-mode file `~/.emacs.d/library-of-babel.org`.
- Add a line `(org-babel-lob-ingest "~/.emacs.d/library-of-babel.org")` to your Emacs conf.
- Collect useful functions in that file, they will be read during emacs startup.

---

The Library-Of-Babel-file is where e.g. the `aggregatebycol1` block from @mutbuerger would be saved to.

Another simple example use-case would be having a code-block, that generates
table data with a header row, but does not mark the headerrow with an `'hline`.
This is not tragic for simple display, but may make further automated processing more involved.
The solution here could be using a small code-block for post-processing from somewhere on the internet:

```
#+name: addhdr
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var tbl=""
(cons (car tbl) (cons 'hline (cdr tbl)))
#+end_src
```

This will simply pipe through the data while splicing in an `'hline` as a second row.

To use this block later in other org files, simply add a `:post`-processing stanza to your data-generating org source block:

```
#+NAME: Example
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :post addhdr(*this*)
'(("Header1" "Column2" "Three")("R1C1V" "2" "C3R1")("4" "5" "6"))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: Example
| Header1 | Column2 | Three |
|---------+---------+-------|
| R1C1V   |       2 | C3R1  |
| 4       |       5 | 6     |
```

You can also easily give pre-existing tables to functions in your LOB:

```
#+NAME: ExData
| h1    | h2    |
| dh1r1 | dh2r1 |
| dh1r2 | dh2r2 |

#+CALL: addhdr(ExData)
```

In my library I have chapters to organize different types of functionality: Data-Generation, Filtering, PrettyPrinting, ...
Just remember to `ingest` again after adding new blocks.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for sharing. Would you have a link to your library-of-babel.org file?